# How to save loaded data from Firestore to Arraylist

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore to keeping data. I want to load data and save it in Array.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_map );

        searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById( R.id.search );
        gpsImage = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.gps_btn );
        info = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.info_btn );
        cafe = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.cafe_btn );
        cafelist_btn = (ImageView)findViewById( R.id.cafelist );


        if(isServicesOK()){
            getLocationPermission();
        }

        db.collection("coll")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                        for (DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot: task.getResult()){
                            placeDetail = new PlaceDetail(querySnapshot.getString("name"),
                                    querySnapshot.getString("address"),
                                    querySnapshot.getString("rating"),
                                    querySnapshot.getString("rates"));

                            namesList.add(placeDetail.getName());
                        }
                    }

                });
        System.out.println("Size: " + namesList.size());
    }
```

In for loop I'm adding loaded data to ArrayList, but my print shows that list is empty. Is there any way to save data to ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

The data probably actually being stored in the ArrayList.  You're just printing the contents of the list before the database query is done.

get() is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the query is done.  The query happens in another thread, then your callback is invoked whatever it's done.

If you move the log statement inside the `onComplete` callback, you'll see the contents of it.  But right now, you are just printing the array before the database query is done.

Comment: Thank you, good to know, but do you have any idea how to save data to ArrayList where query will be done?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "where query will be done".  You can't use the query results until after the query is complete, and it's going to be complete inside that callback.  So, you should only be using the results after that callback is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The data you're trying to print is getting printed before the query fetches the data from firestore. move the code you want to print inside the query and you'll see the result.